# Prob with KSOAP2 in 3G network: XmlPullParserException

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, socketexception, xmlpullparser

I have used KSOAP2 for a web-service call. Here is my code:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            SoapObject result;
            try{
                result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            }catch (ClassCastException e) {
                result = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn; 
            }

            // parse the SOAP object


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // here it is throwing  XmlPullParserException in a #G network
        }
```

The code is running fine when we are testing it in our device and network. I have tested it in different location and different Wifi and 3g network. It is working fine. When my client has tested it using his device and Wifi network, it works fine also. But when he tried the same using 3G network, it is giving `XmlPullParserException`(**expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelopre (position:START_TAG @1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader**). What may be the problem behind this tye of network specific `SocketException`.

Here I like to mention that before calling the SOAP, I have checked the network status using the following code:

```
if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            // we are connected to a network
            //go for SOAP call
        }
```

Comment: can you give entire exception

Comment: As I have not faced that error in my development environment, I have just this error massage, that I have print in any AlertDialog.

Comment: some time may be loos connectivity may loss you connection and so it raise problem.

Comment: are you calling a web service by passing some parameter? Are you using the request.addProperty method anywhere in your code?